# How do I enable the nuget feed "FeedService.svc" in TeamCity 2019.1.2?

Tags: teamcity

I have an older version of Octopus (3.2.3) and it relies on the v1 Nuget feed to be able to retrieve packages.

With the latest TeamCity version (2019.1.2), I am unable to see the FeedService.svc properly and this is causing me errors.

Am I missing some configuration to enable this?

I have enabled the nuget feed on the project level as specified in the documentation and is able to go into the following:

http://{{MyServer}}/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/DefaultFeed/v1/

However, when I go to the url:

http://{{MyServer}}/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/DefaultFeed/v1/FeedService.svc/

I get the following error:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en-US">Could not find container with name: 'FeedService'. 
</message>
</error>
```

What am I missing from the configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

The nuget urls are in: Your Project settings -> NuGet Feed